# Office add-in explicitly mention platform support in manifest

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-store

The `Office add-in` I am working on will be supported only for the `Office Online` platform. There are configuration to set `Host` in which the add-in will work, that can be added in manifest.
Is there a similar setting/configuration available in manifest to explicitly mention that the add-in will support only `Office Online` platform and not Office for Windows, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to publish your Office Add-in to the Office Store (which I assume you are, since you added the `office-store` tag to your question), it must comply with all [Office Store Validation Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies).

As stated in [section 4.12.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies#4-apps-and-add-ins-behave-predictably) of that documentation:

`Your add-in must work across all platforms that support the methods that you define in the Requirements element in your add-in manifest.`

In other words, if your add-in uses requirement sets and methods that are supported cross-platform, then your add-in must work cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

There are three base conceptions behind Office Add-ins as of:

- Security
- Resiliency
- Cross-platform

Your question fall into "Cross-platform" concept which by the way means the following: "*Write once, run everywhere Office runs. Add-ins are currently supported on Windows, Office Online, Mac, and iPad.*"

Basically what you are asking is against of the main concept for Office Add-ins. This means (unfortunately) it **cannot** be done as long as Microsoft follow those concepts. There are no any manifest settings to limit online products version only. By the way we would like to have this too as our desktop version of COM add-in is feature reach and robust.

If you require this manifest option you may post your scenario at [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/)