# Can we configure supported platform directly in manifest

Tags: ms-word, manifest, office-js, office-store

For my word addin that is exposing a taskpane for proprietary linking feature I wanted to remove office online from supported platform. I want this to be available only for Word application in windows and on MAC. Can we do this configuration in manifest file that gets uploaded to office store?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Office add-in explicitly mention platform support in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47827324/office-add-in-explicitly-mention-platform-support-in-manifest) See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100439/disable-word-online-platform-when-publishing-office-js-application-to-store

Comment: This question has been asked before,,.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Word Online platform when publishing office js application to store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52100439/disable-word-online-platform-when-publishing-office-js-application-to-store)

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister, Thanks. Would be grateful If you can help me understand why it is good from design perspective to expose it in all supporting platform and user should not have liberty to choose target platforms. In my case I don't want it  in office online because the documents are secure and it has to be hosted in customer DB. It shouldn't be kept at one drive for anything. Effectively there is no use case for Office online - but very much required in native windows and MAC office. Life would be a lot easier if simply I can configure target platforms somehow in manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, there isn't currently a way to specify deployment platforms in the manifest. Appreciate your feedback about your scenario, and I'll make sure it gets to the right folks.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the current limit it has. Would be happy if this gets addressed by Microsoft team.